# Why CSS radio :checked selector doesn't work?

Tags: css

I wrote a tab component with CSS, the code snippet works very well here, but it doesn't work on my own web page, what's the problem?

```css
.tabs {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  margin: 25px 0;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.tabs .tab {
  margin: 0 5px;
  display: block;
}

.tabs .tab label {
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-left: -1px;
  left: 1px;
  height: 24px;
  line-height: 24px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 10px;
  min-width: 56px;
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
}

.tabs .tab label::before {
  display: none;
}

.tabs .tab label:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.tabs .tab .content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 26px;
  left: 0;
  background: white;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  opacity: 0;
  min-height: 200px;
}

.tabs .tab input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

.tabs .tab input[type="radio"]:checked~label {
  background: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  z-index: 2;
}

.tabs .tab input[type="radio"]:checked~label~.content {
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
  <div class="tab">
    <input type="radio" name="radio_tab" id="t1" checked="checked"><label for="t1">Customers</label>
  </div>
  <div class="tab">
    <input type="radio" name="radio_tab" id="t2"><label for="t2">Users</label>
  </div>
  <div class="tab">
    <input type="radio" name="radio_tab" id="t3"><label for="t3">Roles</label>
  </div>
  <div class="tab">
    <input type="radio" name="radio_tab" id="t4"><label for="t4">Themes</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

The selected radio option was supposed to be displayed selected, but in [my own page](http://walkingp.com/MiUI/index.html#nav_tab) it is not selected.

[image: incorrect]

Comment: it's working on your website

Comment: Works fine for me on your website; perhaps a browser issue?

Comment: Clear your cache.

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve], so we need your CSS as well. Add it to the question.

Comment: My browser is chrome 74.0.3729.169.

Comment: I cannot insert long css code in here, please open http://walkingp.com/MiUI/index.html#nav_tab

Comment: You have to add the CSS, not all of it though, just the essential part that used for the tabs

Comment: @WangHongjian I have replaced your external link with a full working code snippet.